# R model creation does not work

Tags: r, prediction, decision-tree

I'm trying to build a prediction model in R, but no method works. 
I read the data from a csv file to build a list:

```
data <- read.table("data.csv",header=T,sep=";")
```

After that, I filter the data for training:

```
trainings <- data [!is.na(data$isWorking),]
```

Then I use package rpart to create a decision tree

```
tree <- rpart(isWorking ~ ., data=trainings)
```

Followed by make a prediction with the training data to evaluate it

```
prd <- predict(tree, newdata=trainings)
```

Unfortunately I'm not getting 0 and 1 as result for my prediction. Other procedures like knn, randomforest, etc. also doesn't work.

This is the result if I plot the prediction. Usually, it should be values 0 and 1.

[Plot of prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x61A5.png)

Comment: Maybe you want to check/use `type = c("vector", "prob", "class", "matrix")` within the `predict` function that uses your model. The default is `prob` (i.e. probability of your success class), but you can use `class` to get the predicted class (i.e. 0s or 1s). Check here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/rpart/html/predict.rpart.html

Comment: I think the decision tree is incorrect. If I plot it, there are three different possible results. But there should be only two (0 and 1).

Comment: There are 3 results, because there are 3 terminal nodes apparently, each one with a different success probability (i.e. probability of class 1). That is possible even if you have a binary variables. Try `predict(tree, newdata=trainings, type = "class")` as I said above and see what happens. Based on what I think that all your predictions will be of class 0, if you do that above change.

Comment: If I try `type = "class"` then I'll get the following error: Invalid prediction for "rpart" object

Comment: Maybe your 0s and 1s are recognised as numeric and not as groups/labels. Try `trainings$isWorking = factor(trainings$isWorking)` just before you build the model and check again with `type = "class"`

Comment: Now each entry is predicted to 0.

Comment: As I said above, that is expected, because all your predicted probabilities are below 0.5. That means that in any case class 0 is more likely compared to class 1. You have to use the expected probabilities and specify your own threshold. Eg. Anything predicted as 0.35 or above will be of class 1.